# The expression "Peggio di così!"

Tags: meaning

> First, X happened, and then Y. On top of all this, now I have to do Z. **Peggio di così!**

In conversation with my friend, I just heard this unfamiliar phrase. I wonder if it is a short form of "Peggio di così **si muore**!". If so, is it common for native speakers to omit the last two words?

Also: In English, you can place various comparative adjectives in the expression "things couldn't be worse/better/easier". In Italian, do these expressions all take a form similar to "Peggio di così si muore!"?

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessarily a shortening of *Peggio di così si muore*, but more of a shortening of many expressions with more or less the same meaning, all starting with *Peggio di così*. A few examples:

> Peggio di così non può andare
>
> Peggio di così  non si può stare
>
> Peggio di così non è possibile

It is very common in the spoken language to just say the beginning of the sentence and to leave it to the listener to mentally add his/her favorite completion (the meaning will not change much anyway).

To address your edit, yes this expressions are the exact equivalent of the English *Things couldn't be worse*. For example in Italian you can say

> Meglio di così non può andare
> (Things couldn't be better)

Answer (score 1):

Locuzione avverbiale di uso comune. Da [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/peggio/):

> Comparativo dell’avverbio  male, che quindi significa più male, in modo peggiore:
>
> - mi sento peggio; *non poteva finire **peggio  di così***.

You can see usage examples here in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peggio%20di%20cos%C3%AC%2Cpeggio%20di%20cos%C3%AC%20non&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeggio%20di%20cos%C3%AC%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeggio%20di%20cos%C3%AC%20non%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Remember that the OP asked the question in English, so an answer in the same language is expected.